# The link to open the application from the browser does not work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hyperlink, components

I created component with link to Spotify app.
The link is placed in a component that is hidden at the beginning.

and shoud open track in spotify app

I'm trying to put a link in the main component and it's work
Maybe it's because of the component styles. it's hidden from the beginning.

link look like

```
<a class="icon__spotify" href="spotify:track:3nXUfNbkv8ikaSdHwEp0oY"></a>

.modal_wrapper.open {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal_wrapper.close {
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Paste this in the browser search bar: `spotify:track:3nXUfNbkv8ikaSdHwEp0oY`. As you can see, spotify won't open with that. You need to prefix the CSS `href="https://..."` with a proper url pointing to where the browser can find the spotify site. Or...have some (Spotify) JS listening in the background that catches the `href` and automatically sends it to the proper url. Dunno if you have..?

Comment: @RenevanderLende, thanks for the answer
I want it to open in the spotify app when I click on it. If I paste this link "spotify:track:3nXUfNbkv8ikaSdHwEp0oY" into my browser, it
it works, and browser ask open it on spotify

Comment: That must be a browser plugin/extention you have. My Chrome/Edge and Firefox just show a google search page. For the Spotify page to open this would be the proper `href="https://open.spotify.com/track/3nXUfNbkv8ikaSdHwEp0oY"`

Comment: @RenevanderLende, 
I found a way when the link works.
The link is in the parent element of component.
Parent element have onClick event handler.

<div className="modal_wrapper open" onClick={props.close}>

It only handles clicks on the parent. 

 function closeCard(event: React.MouseEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
      setCardOpen(false);
    }
  }

But for some reason clicks on the link stop working when I add onClick handler

Answer (score 0):

The link is in the parent element of component.
Parent element have onClick event handler.
It only handles clicks on the parent.
But for some reason clicks on the link stop working when I add onClick handler

```
export default function Card(props: CardProps) {
  return (
    <div className="modal_wrapper open" onClick={props.close}>
      <div className="card">
        <span className="close_card" onClick={props.close}></span>
        <img
          className="track_image"
          src={props.track.data.albumOfTrack.coverArt.sources[0].url}
          alt="track image"
        />

        <div className="card_content">
          <div className="track">
            <h4 className="track_name">{props.track.data.name}</h4>
            <a
              onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
              target={'_blank'}
              rel="noreferrer"
              className="icon__spotify"
              href={'https://open.spotify.com/track/' + props.track.data.uri.slice(14)}
            ></a>
          </div>
          <h5 className="artists_name">{props.track.data.artists.items[0].profile.name}</h5>
          <h5 className="album_name">
            Album:{' '}
            <a
              onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
              className="album_link"
              href={props.track.data.albumOfTrack.uri}
            >
              {props.track.data.albumOfTrack.name}
            </a>
          </h5>
          <h5 className="track_duration">
            {'Duration: '}
            {new Date(props.track.data.duration.totalMilliseconds).toISOString().slice(14, 19)}
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I add onClick parameter to a tag

```
onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).